# default document directory changes after deleting, re running the application in xcode.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4

I am not sure if it is the expected behavior.

I have xcode 4.3.2, and running an application, where in i get the default Document directory by the following code.

```
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDirectory;
NSString *databasePath;
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDirectory = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: DBNAME]];

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath] == NO) {
        NSLog (@" GETDBPATHNAME: database file does not exist");
    }
    else {
        NSLog  (@" GETDBPATHNAME: Database File EXISTS");
    }
```

Use Cases:
1) I run the application each time in xcode the path is same. 
2) Reboot the device, and re run the application in xcode, also the path is same. 
3) BUT WHEN I DELETE THE APPLICATION, AND RE-RUN IN THE PATH DIFFERS. How it is possible?

What get the path something like:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/Documents/
```

The value  xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx claimed to be a Phone UUID. How it is different each time?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is not a phone UDID. It is rather an app UDID. Therefore it HAS to change when an app is deleted and newly installed.

Answer (score 2):

Each application has a UNIQUE document directory.
When you delete an APP the document directory is also get deleted. Then when you install the same application. The iOS generates another directory for the APP. It never use the previous directory name for this purpose.

Comment: Does that mean the number xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx is not a iPHone ID?

Comment: @Whoami: your path will look like : `/var/mobile/Applications/75088803-4768-4CD6-A561-553F4A182229/MyApp.app/MyApp` Here `75088803-4768-4CD6-A561-553F4A182229` is not UUID. It'll change for each app

Comment: Midhun, i see only the path something like: /var/mobile/Applications/xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/Documents/

Comment: @Whoami: That's the path of your document directory. In the ` /var/mobile/Applications/xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx` there is document folder, your app, library folder and tmp folder. if you take the path of document directory it will be like: ` /var/mobile/Applications/xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx\Documents` and for library ` /var/mobile/Applications/xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx\Library` and so on

Comment: In that case, how can i get as you mentioned MyApp.app/MyApp directory? do i have to create explictly?

Comment: @Whoami: you can't access that. It's automatically created when you install your app. you can check whether myapp.app exist or not (it'll always there)

Comment: No, i did not see anything like mpapp.app, but only i see the path mentioned previously. :(.

Comment: myapp.app means your app file. If your app name is test then it'll be test.app and you cannot access that file. Just check the folder structure of you iOS app in your mac first(it's in library/application support/iphone simulator/.....). Then you'll understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you delete and reinstall the application this path changes.

xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx is not the phone UUID otherwise this path would have been the same for every application. Further More this path is also changed when you update your application on the app store.

So the solution to avoid this problem is to save the path after /Documents Directory and use 
*`stringByAppendingPathComponent:`*

after the path to the Documents Directory to get the full path. In this way you would not have any problem regarding the path of the resource.